# Xamarin MediaElement won't release video source

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, mediaelement

Hi guys I am using MediaElement in Xamarin for video playback of local device files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/mediaelement

The issue I am having is being able to release the video source for MediaElement. I call Stop() and set the Source property to null, yet the last video is still loaded into the MediaElement with playback capabilities.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Here is some of the related code:

```
                             <MediaElement
                                HeightRequest="200"
                                ShowsPlaybackControls="True"
                                BackgroundColor="#141d3d"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                AutoPlay="True"
                                IsVisible="{Binding IsVideoVisible}"
                                Source="{Binding AnprVidSource}"
                                x:Name="meAnpr"
                                KeepScreenOn="True" />
```

Assigning a local address to the source property.

```
AnprVidSource = UserVideo.Path;
```

Code trying to clear the MediaElements source which seems to do nothing

```
            meAnpr.Stop();
            meAnpr.IsEnabled = false;
            viewModel.AnprVidSource = null;
```

Comment: Taking into consideration that the `MediaElement` is still in preview (and by the looks of it, it will be a couple of months more), it is indeed most likely a bug. Take a look into the issues list and if it is not listed there, you can report it: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+mediaelement

Comment: Yes I think you are right @MihailDuchev. I guess what I can do in the meantime is just hide the player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started using MediaElement and now i think i chose the wrong route.This bug is still active.

Once a MediaElement is created,it cannot be set to Hide.IsVisible = false and Source=null has no effect. So,a workaround i found to atleast make it hide is using `Opacity`.

Also, you can't draw an overlay over MediaElement,because for some reason , MediaElement always remains at top.

In my case, i need to show VideoRecorder and MediaElement alternatively and sometimes `Opacity` patch does not work too.So, workaround for this:

```
videoPlayer.PropertyChanged += VideoPlayer_PropertyChanged;
private void VideoPlayer_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if(e.PropertyName == nameof(IsVisible))
        {
          if(videoPlayer.IsVisible){
              videoPlayer.WidthRequest = 500; videoPlayer.HeightRequest = 500;
          }else{
               videoPlayer.WidthRequest = 0; videoPlayer.HeightRequest = 0;
          }
        }            
    }
```

Even if the above solution do not work for you, you will have to create a new MediaElelemnt whenever required and remove the old one.

Maybe this will help others.

Comment: Good idea my friend! Yes for those of us using MediaElement we will have to botch the job for now.

Answer (score 2):

As Milhail Duchev mentioned, it looks to be a bug:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9613

Comment: You can also comment on the issue that you have the same problem. Also, it would help them a lot if you can upload a demo app of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to show that the video had not yet been set and show an icon.

So whenever I needed to set the MediaElement to null or blank,
I set the source to a short mp4 I created from a jpg.

Added the file to Android Resource subfolder

Resources\raw\videonotset.mp4

Set the source

mediaelement.Source = "ms-appx:///videonotset.mp4";

Did the same for the Image element showing the camera icon

Added the file to Android Resource subfolder

Resources\drawable\imagenotset.jpg

Set the source

imageelement.Source = "imagenotset.jpg";